# How do I connect mssql with PDO using php 5.4.19

Tags: php, sql-server

I am gettin following error when I connect to mssql

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server

And  I am using

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=127.0.0.1;database=test;", "sa", "mypassword");
```

I have also added driver in `C:\xampp\php\ext` and set that extension `in php.ini file` 
    [PHP_PDO_MSSQL]
    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

I have tried several tutorials, what exactly I am doing, Please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It may seem trivial, but did you make sure to restart Apache after editing the ini file?

Answer (score 0):

what version of the php pdo sqlsrv are you using?

Try updating it to v3.1 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

You might neet the ODBC driver as well:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434